# link_to a Devise method in Rails 3 produces nothing

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

In a Rails 3.0.6 application that uses Devise I created this link:

```
<%= link_to "client login", new_user_session_path %>
```

I have the following in my header:

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

The link doesn't work. Is the problem with javascript or the devise path?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the "=" :) Change it to :

```
<%= link_to "client login", new_user_session_path %>
```

Comment: Thanks @SpyrosP i tried this and the text for the link showed up the link doesn't work.

Comment: That should work to get the login page. Do you want to post a login or get the login page ? Maybe you want user_session_path with :method => :post ?

Comment: I didn't realize that i was already logged in and that the link would only work if it i wasn't logged in. thanks for your help.

Comment: I did the exact same mistake. Came here googling "link_to produces nothing". What a coincidence. And thank you very much.